# Atomic update with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to maintain a somewhat of counter property in an `Elasticsearch` document, the `update` operation of the counter should be atomic, meaning concurrent update requests should be synchronized.

Does `Elasticsearch` supports such updates? Assuming it's not, what would be the preferred method of managing such 'controlled' updates?

Comment: this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56725207/elasticsearch-optimistic-locking answer might help